# Can I fix the Bulk Insert of inconsistent CSV data using Format File?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, format, bulkinsert, read.csv

I'm trying to load below CSV data to a SQL Server 2019 database table.

Though actual data is starting from Line: 7, yet I needed Line#3 (Valid from) and #4 (Valid to) as well, so I started from the 2nd row. I can filter unwanted rows later on.

However I'm facing 2 challenges.

One is to map the 3rd null fields, after the 2nd comma, to a column in table.

2nd challenge is escape commas (,) inside 2nd column. I've tried many different ways for this e.g. using the Format File (both XML as well as FMT) but no luck.

I've tried different variations of below SQL, by switching on and off different parameters, e.g. when I'm using Format File, then I enable its parameter and disable the params which are coming from the Format File.

```sql
BULK INSERT [KKhan].[t_TestBulkInsert] 
FROM '\\TestFolder\TestHSCV202222.csv'
WITH ( FORMAT = 'CSV',
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        DATAFILETYPE='char',
        FIELDQUOTE = '"',
        KEEPNULLS,
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
        --FORMATFILE = '\\TestFolder\Stat_fmt.xml'
);
```

My Format Files look like this:

```
14.0
3
1       SQLCHAR             0       3999    ","     1     Code                     Latin1_General_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             0       3999    ","   2     Descriptor               Latin1_General_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             0       0    "0x0a"   0     DummyColumn1          

     ""
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="3999" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="3999" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\n" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Code" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Descriptor" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="DummyColumn1" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

[image: CSV Data]

```
Classification report,

New Zealand Harmonised System Classification,

Valid from,01-Apr-2020,

Valid to,Current (as at 06-May-2020),

Lifecycle status,Released,
Audience,OSS,

Code,Descriptor,

01,"Animals; live",

0101,"Horses, asses, mules and hinnies; live",

010121,"Horses; live, pure-bred breeding animals",

0101210010,"Horses; live, pure-bred breeding animals, thoroughbred, race breeding stock, stallions",

0101210015,"Horses; live, pure-bred breeding animals, thoroughbred, race breeding stock, mares",

0101210017,"Horses; live, pure-bred breeding animals, thoroughbred, sport breeding stock, excluding race breeding stock, stallions",

0101210019,"Horses; live, pure-bred breeding animals, thoroughbred, sport breeding stock, excluding race breeding stock, mares",
```

Comment: *.csv/txt flat files always have host of problems where column delimiters, column separators, invisible characters like null terminators \0, special characters based on encoding, and line breaks are in the middle of the actual data.
The most reliable format for data feeds is XML enforced by XSD. An XSD plays a role of a data contract between sender and receiver. It will guarantee proper data format/shape, data types, cardinality, and enforce data quality.

Comment: Your CSV file isn't valid. Different rows have different amount of columns; SQL Server expects the same number of columns per row.

Comment: First two rows have got lesser number of columns, can it not be ignored by using the FIRSTROW = 3  ?